# Is it possible to merge only one sub-repository (subtree) from main repository?

Tags: git, git-subtree

Assume having a MainRepo that includes subtree repositories: subRepoA, subRepoB, SubRepoC.
If I made changes in all of my repositories but would like to merge and push only changes that were done in subRepoB. Is it possible?
It seems MainRepo behaves like one big repository without possibility to distinguish between its sub-repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is both no and yes.  That is, you can achieve what you are asking for, but:

- not with a single simple `git merge` command (it will require additional commands); and
- it's often a *bad idea*.  Be careful!  You may regret it later.  However, if you read through all of the below, and think about how merging works, you *can* do it and can figure out how to update later if necessary.

To do it, though, use:

```
git merge --no-commit
```

and then use `git checkout` or (since Git 2.23) `git restore` to "undo" some of the merge.  Then finish the merge with `git merge --continue` or `git commit`.  See the details below for more information.

#### Background

To understand how you this all works (and why it's a bad idea), remember this about Git:  Git is about commits.  Git is not about *files*, and not even about *branches*.  It's true that commits *contain* files—that's why we have commits, to hold files—and branch names *find* commits, which is why we have branch names.  But in the end, Git is all about *commits*.

- Commits are numbered.  These aren't simple counting numbers: we don't start with commit #1, then have #2, #3, and so on.  Instead, each one has a random-looking (but actually not random at all), unique *hash ID*, which is shown as a big ugly string of letters and digits, often abbreviated since humans will generally just kind of blip over them (is `dca3c76df9bb99b0...` the same as `dca3c76dfb9b99b0...`?).
- No part of any commit can be changed, once it is made.  The reason for this is that the hash ID is actually a cryptographic checksum of every bit of the commit.  If you do take one out, make some changes, and put it back, what you get is a *new* commit with a new and different hash ID.  The old commit, with its unique number, is still there, and anyone who looks up the number gets the old commit.
- Each commit stores two things:

  - There's a full snapshot of every file that Git knows about.  The files are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  (The de-duplication immediately handles the fact that most files in most commits are exactly the same as the versions of those same files in a previous commit.)
  - Meanwhile, each commit stores some *metadata*, i.e., information about the commit itself.  This includes who made it—name and email address—and when, and their log message to explain *why* they made it.  In this metadata, Git stores something that Git itself needs: the commit number of the commit that comes *before* the commit we're looking at here.  Git calls this the *parent commit*.

  The fact that each commit stores the number—the hash ID—of its parent means that, if we can just find the *last* commit in a string of commits, Git can use that to work backwards.  That is, suppose we use single uppercase letters to stand in for the actual hash IDs, and draw the following:

  ```
   ... <-F <-G <-H
  ```

  Using hash ID `H`, Git can retrieve the actual commit—including the snapshot—that you made, whenever you made it.  So that gets you the files.  It also gets Git the metadata, including the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  This means Git can extract *both* commits and compare the files in `G` to those in `H`, to show you what you *changed* in `H`.  Git can also print out the name and email address of the person who made snapshot `G`, and use `G`'s metadata to find commit `F`.  Comparing the snapshot in `F` to that in `G`, Git can show you what *changed* in `G`, and Git can go back to even-earlier commit `F`, and so on.

  Of course, we have to somehow find the hash ID of commit `H`.
- A *branch name* like `master` or `develop` simply holds one (1) hash ID.  But as long as we—or Git—make sure that this is the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, we're all good:

  ```
   ...--F--G--H   <-- master
  ```

  Making a *new* commit requires that Git store the new commit's hash ID into the branch name:

  ```
   ...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
  ```

  Once we make commit `I` (while we're using `master` as the name), Git will *automatically* update `master` so that it points to the *last* commit.  The parent of new commit `I` will be existing commit `H`.

  Since the "arrows" from each commit, pointing to its parent, are part of the commit, they can't be changed.  Like everything in a commit, these are purely read-only.  Note that the arrow coming out of the *branch name* **does** change, though.  So that's why I keep drawing that arrow, while turning the commit-to-commit arrows into simpler lines: we just have to remember that commits point *backwards*, and Git works *backwards*.
- Commits can be on *more than one branch* at a time.  For instance:

  ```
   ...--F--G--H   <-- master, develop
  ```

  Here, both *names* identify commit `H` as their last commit.  So *all* the commits are on both branches.

  The technical term for this is *reachability*.  We're just going to use this lightly below, in merges, but think about starting from commit `H` and working backwards, one commit at a time.  Without moving, we've *reached* commit `H`.  We move back one step, and we've reached commit `G`.  Move back two steps and we're at commit `F`, and so on.
- Note that Git can compare *any two* commits, not just a parent and child pair.  We put the earlier commit on the left (well, normally anyway) and the later commit on the right.  Git then compares the two commits' snapshots.  For files that are the same, Git says nothing at all.  For files that are different, Git figures out some set of changes we can do: *add these lines after line 42, and remove line 86*  This is a *diff:* it shows how to change the left-side file into the right side file.

  If we compare parent and child, this diff listing is *usually* what we did.  But note that Git will just find *a* set of changes.  In some cases, that's not quite *how* we changed it.  The diff Git finds will work, even if we did things a little differently—but sometimes (see merging below), this can cause minor but annoying merge conflicts, that wouldn't happen if Git did a better job here.
- When we use `git push` (or `git fetch` and hence therefore also `git pull`), Git works with *commits*.  A push operation sends *whole commits*.  This includes both the snapshot and the metadata.  The two Gits know which commits each other has by just comparing those hash IDs: this is why the hash IDs are cryptographic checksums of the commits.  Each Git either has a commit, or doesn't.  Whichever Git is sending commits offers the hash ID to the receiving Git, which either says "yes, I need that one, send it" or "no thanks, I already have that one".

#### `git merge` will merge *commits* and make a *merge commit*

The `git merge` command itself merges *commits*.  We like to use it with branch names.  That is, we start out with something like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Because we have two names in this diagram, we need to remember which *name* we are using.  That's where the special name `HEAD` comes in: we attach it to whichever branch we've told Git to use with `git checkout` or (since Git 2.23) `git switch`.  That's the name that will be *updated* when we make a new commit.

So, now we run `git merge branch2`.  Git uses the *name* `branch2` to find *one specific commit:* the one the name points to.  In this case, that's commit `L`.  So two of the interesting commits are commit `J`, the one we are using right now, and commit `L`, the one we named on the command line.

The merge operation, however, actually requires *three* commits.  The third one—or in a way, the first one—is whichever commit is the *best common ancestor* of the other two.  You can think of this as Git looking at the two commits we've already named—`J` and `L` here—and working backwards.  We'll move back as far as we need to, from both commits, until we find some commit we can find *from* both commits.

In this case, the best shared commit is obvious: it's commit `H`.  Commit `H` is on both branches.  Commit `G` is too, but it's further back, so `H` is the *best* one.

To actually accomplish a merge, Git will now diff the merge base—commit `H`—against our current commit, `J`, to see what *we* changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
```

Then Git will diff the *same merge base* against the other commit we named:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

The heart of `git merge`—and what I like to call the verb form, or *to merge*—is now the process of *combining these two diffs*.  Git has found the common starting point, and found two sets of changes: "ours" (from the `HEAD` / current-branch commit), and "theirs" (from the commit we named on the command line).  As long as we and they changed *different files* or *different lines within the same file*,<sup>1</sup> Git itself will be able to do this combining on its own.

Git will repeat this for all files.  Git will apply the combined changes to the snapshot from the merge base (here, commit `H`), and if there are no conflicts, Git will make a new *merge commit* on its own.  This is what I call *merge as a noun*, as the adjective *merge* in front of the word *commit* is often used as a noun, "a merge".

To prevent Git from making this commit on its own, we'll use `--no-commit`.  If we didn't, Git would still stop in the case of a merge conflict (and then you'd have to *resolve* the conflict before committing).

Before we go on to show how to *undo* part of the merge, let's pretend we finished the merge as normal, or left out `--no-commit`, so that we get the final merge commit.  Let's draw it in:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Note that the *name* `branch1` has been updated as usual.  It now points to new *merge commit* `M`.  What makes `M` a merge is simple: it has, instead of the usual single parent commit `J`, *two* parents.  Git adds commit `L` as the *second parent* of the new commit.

The true significance of this new second parent will become clearer in a moment, but note that we're now able to reach both commits `K` and `L` from the name `branch1` and commit `M`, by going down-and-left.  **So now *all* the commits are on (reachable from) the name `branch1`, while commits `I` and `J` are *not* on `branch2`:** they're not reachable from `branch2` because the last commit on `branch2` is commit `L`, whose (single) parent is `K`, whose (single) parent is `H`.  From `H` we can only go *backwards* to `G`, and then to `F` and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup>If we both change (say) line 42, in different ways, Git will not know whether to use our change, or their change, or something different.  Here Git will declare a *merge conflict*, and stop in the middle of the merge, with the merge unfinished.  Your job becomes that of telling Git what the final result should be.

Git will also stop even if our change and their change simply abut (touch): if we replace the old line 42 with a new line 42, and they replace the old line 43 with a new line 43, Git will declare a merge conflict here as well.  This is particularly helpful—yet also particularly annoying—with changes at the top of a file, or at the end, because Git doesn't know which *order* to put those changes in.  For instance, if there is a 10-line file and we add an 11th line and they add an 11th line, which line goes first?  Which line becomes line 12?  Git itself doesn't know, so it makes whoever is doing the `git merge` provide the right answer.

---

#### Using (or abusing?) `--no-commit`

When Git makes the snapshot for merge commit `M`, Git does so in the same way it does for any commit.  We haven't talked about the role of Git's *index* or *staging area* here—and for length reasons, we won't—but the point is that new commit `M` will have a snapshot, just like any other commit.  We can, with `git checkout` or `git restore`, or just by editing the working tree copies of files and using `git add`, change what goes into commit `M`.

So, if we run:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge --no-commit branch2
```

and Git thinks it is all done but *hasn't* made the merge, we can now make particular files—such as every file in some directory—match the copies of those files in the `HEAD` (i.e., current, i.e., `J`) commit:

```
git checkout HEAD -- subdir2 subdir3
```

This will replace, in Git's index and your working tree, all the copies of the files in `subdir2/` and `subdir3/` with those from the `HEAD` snapshot.  Or:

```
git restore -iw --source HEAD subdir2 subdir3
```

which does the same thing.

If you now run `git merge --continue` or `git commit`, Git will now make the snapshot for `M` from the merged files *as updated by this step*.  You will get the same *commit graph* as before:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

What's different is that the *snapshot in commit `M`* now matches the snapshot in commit `J`, *except* for the files that you *didn't* restore, which now contain the merge that Git made automatically, using `H`, `J`, and `L` as the three input commits.

**Note that nothing has changed in the three existing input commits.**  Nothing *can* change, so nothing did.  This means that you can, if you like, re-do this same merge later, with or without `--no-commit`.  Because all commit hash IDs include the time-stamp when computing the cryptographic checksum, a new merge, if and when you make it, will have a different hash ID than existing merge commit `M`.  You may wish to make use of this fact later.

#### Commits *are* the history in a repository

Now that commit `M` exists:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Git will, in essence, believe that commit `M` is the *correct result* of the merge.  Let's add some more commits to `branch1` and `branch2`, in the usual way (`git checkout` or `git switch`, plus the usual work), then get ready to merge `branch2` into `branch1` again:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L--O--P   <-- branch2
```

If we run `git log` we'll see commits `N`, then `M`, then—in some order—`J` and `I` and `L` and `K`—and then `H`, then `G`, and so on.  If we run `git log branch2`, we'll see commit `P`, then `O`, then `L`, then `K`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on.  This is because these are the *reachable commits* from each branch-tip commit.  When traversing backwards through `M`, Git will visit *both legs* of the branch:<sup>2</sup> note that when viewed backwards, a merge is, in effect, a branch (and a branching split, where `H` split into streams `I` and `K`, is a merge).

In any case, if we now run:

```
git merge branch2
```

again (with or without `--no-commit`), Git will go through the usual process to locate the two branch-tip commits `N` and `P` and then work backwards to find the best *shared* commit as the merge base.  In this case, that best shared commit is commit `L`: two steps back from `N` as long as we go down at the fork, and two steps back from `P` as well.<sup>3</sup>

Git will now do the usual diffing, from `L` to `N` to see what we changed, and from `L` to `P` to see what they changed.  If we've used `git checkout` or `git restore` to make files in merge `M` match those in `J`, "what we changed" is to put our stuff from `J` back, and "what they changed" is often *nothing at all*, as the snapshots in `O` and `P`, on `branch2`, won't have to make any *changes* to keep their code.

What this means is that by telling Git that the *right* way to merge `J` and `L` is to *keep the files from `J`*, Git will continue to believe that this is the right way to do the merge.

Note that if you re-perform the merge of `J` and `L` (by checking out either commit as a historical commit, or making a new branch name, and then merging the other commit), Git will still re-do the same work it did the first time we merged `J` and `L`.  That is, *this time*, Git will *again* combine the files that you put back manually.  It's when we do the merge of `N` and `P`, which both have the `M` commit in their history, that Git will "see" the merge we did earlier.

---

<sup>2</sup>This helps show why the word *branch* is problematic in Git.  If we want to be precise, we should use the phrase *branch name* when talking about *names* like `master`, `branch1`, and `branch2`.  Structural branches—where `H` forks if you're reading forwards, or `M` forks when Git is reading backwards—don't have great names.  I like to call them `DAGlets`: see my answer to [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

<sup>3</sup>The fact that it's been 2 steps back each time, on both "legs", is a sort of coincidence forced by me trying to draw pretty graphs.  Often it's a different number of steps on each leg, and in some cases, it's *no* steps back from one or both commits.  However, when going no steps back, the merge is either trivial (and Git will do something else—not actually merging—by default) or already done (and Git will just say that you're up to date and do nothing).

---

#### Summary

- The merging action—the *to merge* part of `git merge`—merges *commits*.  That is, it looks at the snapshots in each commit.
- The merge process uses the history, which is a result of the *graph* recorded by earlier commits (including merge commits), to find the merge base.
- You can deliberately pause Git after the merge-as-a-verb part and make changes.
- When you finish this part, and use `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to make the merge-as-a-noun, the resulting snapshot will be whatever you made it to be, while Git was paused.

This is how you can achieve what you want.  Since you're dealing with `git-subtree` elsewhere (I assume), the fact that this makes a later merge "harder" in some sense may be irrelevant: if you need updated `subdir2` files, you can just `git checkout` or `git restore -iw` them from the appropriate commit.